# Including an image in a rich text field

Tags: image, blob, oracle-apex, richtext

I'm using Apex 4.2 and Oracle 11.g.

I have a rich text field that is used to store the body of an apex-generated eMail using SMTP_MAIl.  The eMail generation process works fine.  But my users want to include an image (jpg, bmp, etc.) into the body of the email, and don't want to include the image as an attachment.

On the Apex page, the rich-text field is defined as a Rich Text Editor / CDK Editor 3 / Toolbar = Full / Toolbar Expanded = Yes / Skin = Office 2003.

The rich-text  field writes to a BLOB column.

If I just paste in the image (Shift / Insert) and then go to save the rich text field, I get a 500 - Internal Server Error.

Can you provide some help so that I can include an image in the rich text field?  Ultimately, this will be included in the body of an html_email.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of my problem seems to be related to the 32K limit per Apex page item.
A colleague told me to look for a plugin.  I found Enkitec's "CLOB LOAD" plugin.  https://www.enkitec.com/products/plugins/clob-load
The plugin works well.  It's easy to install, and the directions are pretty clear.
I stumbled on a few things to supplement CLOB_LOAD directions.
1) The table item that the Rich Text will write to has to be defined as a CLOB (and not a BLOB).
2) You have to create a Apex Collection using Apex's SQL Workshop.  Be sure to include the Begin and End.  The directions reference this.
3) If you already setup the form Apex page using the Apex Wizard and the DML page process is there, The "Return Key Into Item" is empty.  At least it was with my Apex Page (4.2).  That prevented the "Create" button from working.  Once I set the "Return Key Into Item" value to the page item that relates to the primary key column of the table, it helped.
4) I also had to copy the page process for the "Save" button suggested by the plugin directions and assign the copied process to the "Create" button.  Once I set those two items up, the plugin worked fine for updating as well as creating.  It's a good solution.

Using this plugin, I can place a JPG, PNG, GIF, etc. into the Rich Text field, and it will write it to the CLOB, even when the total page item is greater than 32K.